# Want to get products available quantity based on location (odoo 12)

Tags: python, treeview, odoo

I need to get products available quantity per warehouse and preview it as a column in products view list.

Can anyone please guide me what is wrong with the following code?

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    warehouse1_quantity = fields.Float('RYD Qty', compute='product_qty_ warehouse1_check')

    @api.multi
    def product_qty_ warehouse1_check(self): 
    for record in self:
          product = self.env['product.product'].browse(PRODUCT_ID)
          warehouse1_quantity = product.with_context({'warehouse' : 'RYD Inventory'}).qty_available 
          record.warehouse1_quantity
```

```
    <record id="product_template_view_tree_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.view.tree.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[last()]" position="after">
                <field name="warehouse1_quantity"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not assigned the value to the object variable.

It should be like :

```
record.warehouse1_quantity = product.with_context({'warehouse' : 'RYD Inventory'}).qty_available
```